# Improving Bubble sort by making it notice where the last swap took place

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

How do I improve this code to make it Instead of reducing `i` by one each time, set it to where the last swap took place (the lower position). If no swaps took place, `i` should get set to zero, which will end the loop

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void bubbleSort(T[] a) {
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            numComp++;
            if (a[j].compareTo(a[j + 1]) > 0) {
                numAsgn += 3;
                T temp = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        if (tracing) {
            System.out.println("one more bubbled up: "
                    + Arrays.toString(a));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my attempt at it.

```
 public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void bubbleSort(T[] a) {
    boolean swap = false;
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i > 0;) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            numComp++;
            if (a[j].compareTo(a[j + 1]) > 0) {
                numAsgn += 3;
                T temp = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
            if (swap) {
                i = j;
            } else {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        if (tracing) {
            System.out.println("one more bubbled up: "
                    + Arrays.toString(a));
        }
    }
}
```

The code that prints my output is the following:

```
 bubbleSort(check);
    System.out.printf("%1$-19s %2$10d %3$19d %4$19d", "Bubble", numComp, numAsgn, numComp + numAsgn);
    System.out.println();
    resetCounts(); //resets numComp and numAsgn to 0
```

Input example: [2, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Explain what you have tried.

Comment: I don't believe that you can do a lot of improvements here.

Comment: @NiVeR my professor wants me to improve it like I described above.

Comment: I dont understand why I got downvoted. Whoever downvoted me I'd like to see you help rather than be useless.

Comment: You most probably got downvoted because you did neither explain your solution nor what the problem with your code is. When seeking debugging advice, you should always provide a [MCVE] (this includes sample input with expected and observed output).

Comment: @Turing85 I provided all that. Are you able to help me now?

Comment: First of all, you did not provide everything I asked for. You did not provide a complete example. The code you provided is not complete, it is missing a `main(...)` method. Furthermore, you provided an expected output, but neither the corresponding input nor the observed output. And you did not explain what the problem is. Second, I never intended to help, I just tried to explain why the downvote occured.

Comment: @Turing85 How about now dude? Why do you gotta be so difficult I just couldn't figure out how this tweak works, its supposed to be a helping community here not for criticizing people.

Comment: @Turing85 providing a complete example shouldn't necessarily always include `main()`. In this case, for example, it is okay to not include it because all the code of concern is contained within a single method that provides the necessary context.

Comment: @NickSilvestri I tend to disagree. The problem is much easier to grasp with a concrete example, i.e. sample input, expected and observed output. This is the basis for debugging the program.

Comment: @Turing85 I would agree with you, in general case, but here we have a sort function and we know what it should produce. Also the description makes clear what the OP is trying to achieve..

Comment: @NiVeR If one is willing to write one's own `main`... to get the program running (or if one is able to solve the problem by just looking at it), that is totally fine. You will, however, get more people interested in helping you by providing as much groundwork as possible. Please keep in mind that I did not downvote the question, I just try to explain possible reasons for the downvote.

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void bubbleSort(T[] a) {
    int lastSwap = a.length - 1, i;
    for (i = lastSwap; i > 0;) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            numComp++;
            if (a[j].compareTo(a[j + 1]) > 0) {
                numAsgn += 3;
                T temp = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
                lastSwap = j;
            }
        }
        if(i == lastSwap) {
            //sorted
            break;
        }
        i = lastSwap;
        if (tracing) {
            System.out.println("one more bubbled up: "
                    + Arrays.toString(a));
        }
    }
}
```

This should give you some improvement, but the worst case remains the same, as expected.

Comment: This code does an infinite loop im guessing, my program didnt stop running @NiVeR

Comment: @Elias Try now.

Comment: Thank you that works, I really appreciate your help. @NiVeR